# Leading substrings exercise

Tags: strings, ruby, array

I have a couple of answers that I wrote up for this exercise. Both of my methods work. I'm hoping to get some feedback on each and how I could improve them, if needed.

The idea is to take a string, such as 'abc' and return an array like this: `['a', 'ab', 'abc']`

For the second method, I used `#map`, but I'm not sure if this is the best way to achieve my desired result.

```
def substrings(string)
  subbed = []
  (0..string.length-1).each do |i|
    subbed.push(string.slice(0..i))
  end
  return subbed
end

def substrings2(string)
  string.split('').map.with_index do |c,i|
    string.slice(0..i)
  end
end


print substrings2('abc')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- In Ruby, there are enough `Enumerable` and `Array` methods that you
  virtually never need to initialize an empty array and iterate to push
  values.
- Your method doesn't return every substring in the string. `'bc'` isn't present for example. Your method shouldn't be called `substrings`. Your title suggests `leading_substrings`.

Here's a clear, short way to initialize this array with [`Array.new`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-c-new) :

```
def leading_substrings(string)
  Array.new(string.size) { |i| string[0..i] }
end

p leading_substrings('abc')
# ["a", "ab", "abc"]
```

Comment: Oh, cool. Ok, thank you. And yes you are correct, it was leading substrings, not all the substrings.

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for is known as a "scan" in functional programming.  Surprisingly, ruby's `Enumerable`, which is where this method belongs (since what you're doing is not, ultimately, specific to strings), does not provide a `scan` method or its equivalent.

But we can write one easily enough:

```
module Enumerable
  def scans
    reduce([]) {|m,x| m << (m.last || []) + [x]}
  end  
end
```

Now we have a general purpose method which we can use like so:

```
[9] pry(main)> (1..5).to_a.scans
=> [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Your original problem now becomes a simple delegation to `scans`:

```
[14] pry(main)> 'abc'.split('').scans.map(&:join)
=> ["a", "ab", "abc"]
```

Comment: It's a great idea if `Enumerable#scans` is used in other places with other objects than strings. Otherwise, it's a bit of an overkill, with many temp objects and methods.

Comment: Yes, if you're _just_ trying to solve the given problem, it's overkill.  The point is that if you're a functional programmer, you recognize this immediately as a scan, and it just happens to be a deficiency of Enumerable that it lacks a scan method.  So i just created the method I should have had anyway, and now I have a clean 1 line solution, albeit not the most performant one.  Fwiw, for just the problem at hand, I do prefer your solution.

Comment: This is great. I'm still new to programming, so got a lot to learn before I'M able to switch careers.

@Jonah is it ok if I copy this? I need to pick it apart and learn how it works on a deeper level.

Comment: Sure, do whatever you like with it :)

Answer (score 2):

Your second method is closer to idiomatic Ruby. In general, you should never need to initialize an array. `chars` is a nice alternative to `split('')`. And, you can open String and add a new method. I would do:

```
class String
  def substrings
    chars.map.with_index { |_char, index| slice(0..index) }
  end
end
```

Then:

```
'abc'.substrings
```

Comment: Opening the `String` class is a very bad idea, known as _monkey patching_. One should never do this.

Comment: This is not correct. Monkey patching a class with a related method is considered normal practice in Ruby (and is prevalent throughout Rails). I generally recommend using refinements to achieve the same thing, but it is more complex than needed for this example.

Comment: Oh, OK. Then the Ruby people must be very disciplined.